# Reference request: The Steenrod squares generate all stable cohomology operations

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, cohomology-operations

The isomorphy of the Steenrod algebra to the cohomology of an Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum is a direct corollary of Brown representability and the fact, that all stable cohomology operations are generated by the Steenrod squares. However, for the latter I don't find a reference with a sound proof. May omits the proof in his Concise Course.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

See for example

Switzer, Robert M. Algebraic topology-homotopy and homology. Springer, 2017 (Chapter 18)

Norman Earl Steenrod, and D. B. A. Epstein. Cohomology operations. No. 50. Princeton University Press, 1962

Comment: Do you know, where in Steenrod's book this is proved? I have been scanning through it several times, he occupies himself quite much with discussion of the Steenrod squares, but I am unable to find the exact statement, that the Steenrod algebra is in fact the algebra of all cohomology operations.

Comment: Sorry, my memory was deceptive. In fact, Steenrod and Epstein only mention without proof that the Steenrod algebra is isomorphic to the cohomology of the adequate Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum (p.29). However, they give references to papers by Serre and Cartan.